# mysql lookup two tables using like

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with the following query, it partially seems to work before giving up the ghost. I'm no guru but I'd be grateful for any help offered.

I have two tables

### cms_tags

```
key  | tag          |  timesused
---------------------------
1     retriever        12
2     jack retriever   1
3     energetic        5
4     bulldog          3
```

### cms_doggies  (four fields = key,dogname,description,tags)

```
key   dogname         description                                                                                                                                               tags
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Jack Retriever  Jacks only just been with us for a short while he's a golden retriever that is energetic and loves to play with a frisbee. Does not like canned food.     ,retriever,golden,energetic,frisbee
```

the query should return:

```
retriever
jack retriever
energetic
```

...instead it only returns:

```
jack retriever
```

here's the query:

```
$dogname= strtolower($_GET['dogname'])
$description= strtolower($_GET['description'])
$tags= strtolower($_GET['tags'])

SELECT `key`, `tag` 
  FROM `cms_tags` 
 WHERE `tag` LIKE '%$dogname%' 
    OR `tag` LIKE '%$description%' 
    OR `tag` LIKE '%$tags%' 
ORDER BY `primkey` 
LIMIT 0, $finalnumber;
```

Comment: A couple of speculative suggestions... 1) Are you sure there are no leading spaces in the inputs? 2) What happens if you remove the `LIMIT` line?

Comment: Do you know what the inputs are?  It seems fairly likely that `$finalnumber` being `1` would be causing your problem.  Can you post the exact query you are doing, including the filled-in inputs?

Comment: Looks like you have your LIKES the wrong way around - I would expect that '$dogname' LIKE '%' + tag + '%' would be much more relevant.

Comment: @WillA: Full Text Searching (FTS) would be a much better approach: http://www.fastechws.com/tricks/sql/full-text-search-boolean.php

Comment: /me sounds the SQL injection vulnerability alarm

Comment: @OMG Ponies - so would normalizing the database!  :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$tags` parameter has the value `',retriever,golden,energetic,frisbee'`, so there are no matching rows. Instead of using `LIKE`, try using `IN ([Value list])`.

**Example:**

```
SELECT key, tag
FROM cms_tags
WHERE tag IN ('retriever','golden','energetic','frisbee')
```

This query will return every row where the `tag` field has any of the values in the list. Notice, however, that you cannot use wildcards.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi

thanks I used the following query 

SELECT * FROM `cms_tags` WHERE `tag` IN ('$dogname') OR `tag` IN ('$description') OR `tag` IN ('$tags') ORDER BY `key` LIMIT 0, $number;

this gave a result of 

jack retriever

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help especially to OMG ponies for pointing me in the FTS direction, I ended up doing the following

```
ALTER TABLE cms_tags ADD FULLTEXT(tag); 
ALTER TABLE cms_doggies ADD FULLTEXT(dogname, description, tags);

SELECT * FROM cms_tags WHERE MATCH (tag) AGAINST ('$dogname $description $tags') LIMIT 0, $number;
```

the query now returns

retriever
jack retriever
energetic

as these are in the cms_tags table it also returns

play
food

I'll have to figure out a way to filter common words like these.

Once again thanks for all your help.

Comment: do not answer your questions; edit them instead to add additional information.